# Ошибка Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.4.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle

Создал проект, пытаюсь его развернуть получаю ошибку:

```
Build file '.../build.gradle' line: 3

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.4.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Вот сам `gradle.build`:

```
plugins {
               id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
               id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
         }
```

третья строка это `id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false`. Подскажите, что это за ошибка и почему она возникает.

Файл `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

оказалось ошибка с proxy в android studio, но стал делать build gradle через системный терминал (там стоит ip Франфуркта) получил такую же ошибку. Сделал build gradle --scan получил

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
> Could not download gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.10.2.jar (com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.10.2)
   > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.10.2/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.10.2.jar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.10.2/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.10.2.jar'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
```

и теперь вопрос что значит `Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required`

Comment: Какая у версия IDE и версия gradle wrapper? Если создать проект заново, такая же будет ошибка?

Comment: Оффлайн режим gradle выключен? Интернет, VPN, proxy - всё работает, [репозиторий гугла](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html) доступен?

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan Ide Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1. В принципе это и есть новый проект.

Comment: @woesss да как оказалось на самом android studio не работает прокси. И Это странно на самой системе работает

Comment: У студии своя настройка и изначально стоит "no proxy". `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | HTTP Proxy`

Comment: У меня была подобная проблема после открытия старых проектов на новом ПК, решалась она выбором JDK - переключение 8 на 11:
`File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Gradle JDK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему путем покупки vpn

Answer (score 0):

Недавно была такая же ситуация со старым проектом на github, нервы чекала целый день.

- скачал последний Android Studio
- выключил и включил режим toggle offline mode (похоже он глючный)
- сменил targetSdk и compileSdk проекта на 34
- Refactor-Migrate Build config to Gradle Build file
- закрыл и открыл проект
- file-Invalidate Caches со всеми 3 галками
- закрыл и открыл проект
- он предложил обновить gradle до 8.2 и AGP  (android gradle plugin)
- обновил и кнопка refresh (не Revert!!)
- он предложил обновить Java до 17.0.7, обновил
- закрыл и открыл проект и о чудо все заработало.